# Camel JMS request/Reply timeouts

Tags: jms, apache-camel

I am trying to send request/reply a message to a remote broker from camel but the it times out. See config below:

```
 <bean id="providerJMSConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
  <property name="alwaysSessionAsync" value="false"/>
  <property name="alwaysSyncSend" value="true"/>
  <property name="brokerURL"><value>${remote-broker-broker-url}</value></property>
  <property name="clientID" value=""/>
  <property name="closeTimeout" value="15000"/>
  <property name="copyMessageOnSend" value="true"/>
  <property name="disableTimeStampsByDefault" value="false"/>
  <property name="dispatchAsync" value="false"/>
  <property name="objectMessageSerializationDefered" value="false"/>
  <property name="optimizeAcknowledge" value="false"/>
  <property name="optimizedMessageDispatch" value="true"/>
  <property name="password" value=""/>
  <property name="producerWindowSize" value="0"/>
  <property name="statsEnabled" value="false"/>
  <property name="useAsyncSend" value="false"/>
  <property name="useCompression" value="false"/>
  <property name="useRetroactiveConsumer" value="false"/>
  <property name="userName" value=""/>
  <property name="watchTopicAdvisories" value="true"/>
  <property name="sendTimeout" value="0"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="providerJMSConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="aeroProviderJMSConnectionFactory"/>
  <property name="deliveryPersistent" value="true"/>
  <property name="explicitQosEnabled" value="true"/>  
  <property name="priority" value="${jms-message-priority}"/>
  <property name="acceptMessagesWhileStopping" value="false"/> 
 </bean>
 <bean id="providerJMS" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
  <property name="configuration" ref="aeroProviderJMSConfig"/>  
 </bean>

  <osgi:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="true">
   <endpoint id="providerEndpoint" uri="providerJMS:queue:provider?replyTo=providerResponse&requestTimeout=120000"/>
<route>
<from .....>
<to ref="providerEndpoint"/>
....
</route>
<osgi:camelContext>
```

Why does this happen? I realised on the remote broker the number of consumers are always more than 1 even though I did not specify how many consumers it should have. Also, whene I removed the replyTo destination, the name still keep coming up on the remote broker.

Pls, is there any tool I can use to debug activemq so that I can see who is picking messages off a queue?

Answer (score 2):

When doing request/reply over JMS with Camel, it uses a 20 sec default timeout. Is it that timeout you hit?

You can alter it, its the requestTimeout option
http://camel.apache.org/jms